# Windows 7 compatibility mode on network share

Tags: windows-7, admin, compatibility, elevated-privileges, compatibility-mode

I have a network file share with a number of shortcuts in it, each of which runs one of several applications which load data into them from that particular file share. The network file share & applications are located on a system running Server 2003, and all permissions on that file share have been unchanged.

The applications run fine when executed from a system running Windows XP.  One system was just changed to Windows 7.  In running the applications on Windows 7, the user was (then) a local administrator on that Windows 7 system.  Initially, they each functioned properly, and I was able to print from one particular application. However, when the user is now no longer a local administrator on that system, the application will not print, saying it requires local admin permissions to do so.  You can get around it by right-clicking and running with elevated permissions on the shortcut - the application will print & function fine.

However, remembering to right-click & run with elevated privileges is not easily remembered, especially when you've navigated down several levels in the application only to find you're unable to print from within the application.

The shortcuts are located either by using UNC names or by mapped drives (depending on the user).  In my test, I'm using the UNC name -

```
\\servername\datafolder\content\myshortcut.lnk
```

If I go to Properties on the shortcut, the Compatibility Mode is greyed out and cannot be changed.  However, if I go to the Troubleshoot Compatibility & accept the recommended settings - the application executes fine.  However, when it tries to save the changes the Troubleshooter recommends, it says that the application is incompatible.  (FWIW, the Fix Application sets CompatMode = #WINXPSP2 and UserVerifySolution = Verify_YES).

Short of:

1. Remembering to run the shortcut with elevated permissions, OR
2. Making the user an admin on the local system

is there a way to apply changes in compatibility mode across a number of shortcuts on a network share without making more of a mess, or opening these shortcuts with elevated privileges?

Thanks,

SC